some problems we meet in LLMs
When we try to run python src/train_web.py inllama3 firstly the problem is

ImportError: This modeling file requires the following packages that were not found in your environment: flash_attn. Run pip install flash_attn

Then we did pip install flash_attn and try again
this time the problem became this:
ImportError: /home/mobinets/anaconda3/envs/llama3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flash_attn_2_cuda.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c104cuda14ExchangeDeviceEa

We hope to know how to deal with this problem and the reason.

Looks like you installed flash_attn that was not compiled for your specific system. You can uninstall that version with pip uninstall flash-attn and reinstall with
FLASH_ATTENTION_FORCE_BUILD=TRUE pip install flash-attn
